# Change status of "Approval Status" column to "Rejected"

Tags: workflow, infopath, approval, status

I have an InfoPath form with a button "Cancel". This button cancels the workflow is running. I created an EventReceiver and I'm able to change "Approval 2010" column to Cancel but I cannot change the "Approval Status" column to "Reject", still in "Draft".

My code:

```
private void ItemCanceled(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
                {
                    using (SPSite elevSite = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
                    using (SPWeb elevWeb = elevSite.OpenWeb(properties.RelativeWebUrl))
                    {

                        using (DisabledEventsScope scope = new DisabledEventsScope())
                        {

                            SPList elevList = elevWeb.Lists[properties.ListId];
                            SPListItem elevListItem = elevList.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId);
                            SPWorkflowManager workflowManager = elevSite.WorkflowManager;
                            SPWorkflowAssociationCollection workflowAssociations = properties.List.WorkflowAssociations;
                            SPWorkflowAssociation workflowAssocation2010 = workflowAssociations.GetAssociationByBaseID(AdministrativeFormsUtility.ApprovalTemplateId2010);

                            var itemWorkflowsCompleted = elevListItem.Workflows
                                 .Cast<SPWorkflow>()
                                 .Where(w => w.AssociationId == workflowAssocation2010.Id).ToList();

                            if (itemWorkflowsCompleted.Any())
                            {
                                Logger.Info(Title, string.Format("Verifying if a workflow is running on item '{0}'...", elevListItem.File.Name), Category);

                                foreach (SPWorkflow mySPWorkflow in itemWorkflowsCompleted)
                                {
                                    foreach (SPWorkflowTask taskWorkflow in itemWorkflowsCompleted[0].Tasks)
                                    {


                                        //cycle throught all tasks associated to the workflow
                                        bool result = false;
                                        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
                                        ht["PercentComplete"] = 1.0f;
                                        ht["Status"] = "Completed";
                                        ht["TaskStatus"] = "Rejected";
                                        ht["ows_FieldName_Comments"] = "Rejected";

                                        result = SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(taskWorkflow, ht, true);

                                        Logger.Info(Title, string.Format("Removed workflow instance '{0}'", mySPWorkflow.InstanceId), Category);


                                    }
                                    SPWorkflowManager.CancelWorkflow(mySPWorkflow);
                                    Logger.Info(Title, string.Format("Canceled workflow instance '{0}'", mySPWorkflow.InstanceId), Category);
                                    SendEmailCanceled(properties);
                                    properties.ListItem["Approval Status"] = "1";
                                    properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate();

                                }


                            }

                            else
                            {
                                Logger.Info(Title, string.Format("No running workflow instances detected."), Category);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `elevListItem["Approval Status"] = 1; elevListItem.SystemUpdate();` instead of assigning a string value, or use the `SPModerationStatusType` enum you cast to int.

Comment: properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate(); doesn't updated the item.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you might want to use `elevListItem` instead. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
SPModerationInformation moderationInformation = properties.ListItem.ModerationInformation;
moderationInformation.Status = SPModerationStatusType.Denied;
properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate();
```

Comment: The line: properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate(); doesn't updated the item, change the value from Denied to Draft. I'm site collection admin so I don't understand why doesn't update.